# How to add a custom field button in Virtuemart

Tags: virtuemart

I hope this question has a simple answer. I am creating a product catalogue with Joomla 2.5.6 and VirtueMart version 2.0.8e. On the product details page I want to include my own pdf button which will link to the brochure of the product.

Under the suggestion of a reply on the Virtuemart form, I created an image custom field in virtuemart but encountered two major problems.

1. I don't know now to link the image to a pdf.
2. I can't seem to remove the title from the image.

http://aleksdesign.ca/joomla/component/virtuemart/software-and-solutions/streem-alert-detail?Itemid=0

Please advise.

Thanks,
Aleks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the Virtuemart Files feature.  From the admin control panel, under "Shop", choose "Media".  There you can upload the file(s) that you want to have downloaded.  Be sure to associate them with a product, and they'll be included on the product page for download.  To make a button out of the link(s), you could investigate using CSS to style them as a button.  The only alternative I can think of would be to build a custom plugin for VM, which would be a great deal of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

To make Custom fields in **Joomla Virtuemart 2.0** is so simple.
You need to open your **administrator** and then go to:

**Virtuemart->Products->Custom Field**

there you will find a link to create new custom fiels and you can create your custom field with your choice. It provides various Custom Field Types. After creating and saving your custom field you need to go to product whom you want to add it. like:

**Products->your product name->**

open your product and go to **Custom Fields** and there at bottom you can see your custom field. add your custom field to product, save it and check this product from front-end of your site.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks.